# structure in modular arithmetic

Tags: discrete-logarithm, modular-arithmetic, differential-analysis

I was playing around with modular arithmetic when I noticed something.

\begin{align}
g^k &= a \bmod n\\
g^{k+0.5(n-1)} &= b \bmod n
\end{align}

Then $a + b = n$, so you can also write

$$g^{k+0.5(n-1)} = n - a \bmod n$$

This seems to hold if $n$ is prime and $g$ is the primitive element of $n$, according to randomly trying sets of $n$ and $g$. I have tried to see the theory behind this, but was not able to do so. None of the properties ([Wikipedia: Modular arithmetic properties](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modular_arithmetic#Properties)) of modular arithmatic seems to relate to this. Can someone explain why this holds?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you know the [Fermat's little theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fermat's_little_theorem), that is, $g^{n-1} = 1 \mod n$, then you can understand what you found.

The point is that

$$b^2 = g^{2k + n-1} = g^{2k}g^{n-1} = g^{2k} = a^2 \mod n$$

Therefore, $b = a$ or $b = -a$ in $\mathbb{Z}_n$. But $b = -a$ means that $b = n-a$, since $n = 0$ modulo $n$.

Comment: Thank you for explaining. This shows that the first 0.5n numbers of the order  influences the second 0.5n numbers, right? So, there is some structure in the 'random' modular arithmetic

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by the "first 0.5n numbers of the order", sorry.